# how to disable external links in magento for seo perspective?

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, css, seo, html

i analyzed my website on seoptimer.com for seo optimization and the result was this:

> Optimize the number of external links

```
https://mysite.com/customer/account/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/
https://mysite.com/customer/account/login/
https://mysite.com/customer/account/create/
http://themeforest.net/item/fortis-flexible-magento-theme/1744309?ref=infortis
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/333/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/314/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/114/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/25/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/125/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/402/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/145/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/133/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/303/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/446/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/228/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/310/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/243/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/119/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/77/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/304/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/325/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/88/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/383/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/14/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/124/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/34/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/51/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/273/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/177/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/247/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/195/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/269/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/139/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/162/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/84/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/335/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/322/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/163/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/83/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/250/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/73/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/259/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/254/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/161/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/434/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/107/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/237/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/305/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/316/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/63/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/445/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/45/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/286/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/299/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/70/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/185/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/181/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/211/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/186/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/265/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/44/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/50/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/263/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/423/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/65/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/207/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/208/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/183/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/438/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/72/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/409/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/264/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/49/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/47/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/210/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/204/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/212/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/349/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/66/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/270/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/180/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/291/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/300/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/268/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/298/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/67/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/12/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/296/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/350/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/209/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/43/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/46/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/42/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/301/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/206/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/68/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/443/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/184/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/205/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/345/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/359/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/418/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/352/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/440/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/351/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/353/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/370/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/426/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/405/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/343/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/421/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/432/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/398/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/424/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/429/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/417/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/408/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/437/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/13/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/397/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/428/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/355/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/368/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/342/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/406/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/338/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/369/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/307/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/442/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/433/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/407/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/358/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/436/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/419/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/441/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/346/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/420/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/356/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/422/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/425/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/365/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/367/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/347/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/371/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/327/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/363/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/364/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/354/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/416/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/122/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/159/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/101/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/97/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/98/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/105/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/100/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/123/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/121/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/99/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/102/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/93/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/104/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/103/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/94/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/95/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/92/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/91/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/96/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/400/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/401/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/403/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/wishlist/index/add/product/404/form_key/jvlu7nIE7EfwX2Of/
https://mysite.com/sales/guest/form/
```

i checked these links and i couldn't find any external links what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Magento.SE!

These aren't external links, but, rather, how Magento handles internal links in your own site.

Looking at some of the biggest Magento sites (in this case www.stelladot.com) you'll see that it isn't uncommon to have internal links be fully qualified. Here's a look at their homepage:

[image]

And a look at the wishlist link on the PDP:

[image]

I wouldn't worry about these at all and I would ignore the report.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the report is flagging all links that start with https as being external (i.e. all the secure actions and pages of the website). There are a few options in order of what I would personally do:

1. Ignore this section of the report and trust search engines can tell that it is the same website. Only the themeforest.net link is external.
2. Edit your admin settings to set the Base URL to start with https as well.
3. Add rel="nofollow" onto those specific links by editing the theme files appropriately.